# Android Thread Concurrent running threads notify between them

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to execute the method `uploadingDone()` after completion of all three threads.
The flags are working most of time correct. In rare case all three flags set to true and `BLOCK1` get executed twice. All three threads are doing different tasks on different data ( No Concurrent modification can occur).

Can I eliminate the flags with any native function on thread?

All three threads to be run in parallel(Mandatory Requirement.).
BLOCK1 should be called **only once**.

```
private synchronized void uploadingDone(){

    if( isItemUploaded && isListUploaded && isStoreUploaded){
        uploadingDone = true;
         //<BLOCK1>
        //TODO move to next screen
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG, "uploadingDone: Failed");
    }
}

private boolean isListUploaded = false, isItemUploaded = false, isStoreUploaded = false, uploadingDone = false;


private class ListUpload extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        isListUploaded = true;
        Log.i(TAG, "ListUpload Thread started");
        if(!uploadingDone)
            uploadingDone();
    }

}

private class ItemUpload extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "ItemUpload Thread started");
        isItemUploaded = true;
        if(!uploadingDone)
            uploadingDone();
    }
}

private class StoreUpload extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "StoreUpload Thread started");
        isStoreUploaded = true;
        if(!uploadingDone)
            uploadingDone();
    }

}

private ListUpload listUpload;
private StoreUpload storeUpload;
private ItemUpload itemUpload;

public void startUpload(){

    listUpload = new ListUpload();
    listUpload.start();

    storeUpload = new StoreUpload();
    storeUpload.start();

    itemUpload = new ItemUpload();
    itemUpload.start();

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip the flags and add

```
listUpload.join();
storeUpload.join();
itemUpload.join();
// <BLOCK1>
```

at the end of startUpload(). Each call to join() will cause the calling thread to block until the given thread finishes.

Comment: I don't understand, could you rephrase your question?

Comment: No, all threads are running concurrently. They start as soon as you call start(). Make sure you start() all threads before you join() any thread, like so: t1.start(); t2.start(); t3.start(); t1.join(); t2.join(); t3.join();

Comment: my apologies. That's what I made mistake. I did start and added threads so they ran sequentially. :) I fixed. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I modified my source as claesv mentioned.
I m posting my resultant code to show how this Thread.join method simplified my task.
Hope will help someone.

```
private void uploadingDone(){

if( isItemUploaded && isListUploaded && isStoreUploaded){
    uploadingDone = true;
     //<BLOCK1>
    //TODO move to next screen
}else{
    Log.i(TAG, "uploadingDone: Failed");
    showFailureAlert();
}
}

// These flags are used to VALIDADTION success of uploading process. No need if you no need validation to move screen.

private boolean isListUploaded = false, isItemUploaded = false, isStoreUploaded =   false, uploadingDone = false;


private class ListUpload extends Thread{

@Override
public void run() {
    isListUploaded = true;
    Log.i(TAG, "ListUpload Thread started");
}

}

private class ItemUpload extends Thread{

@Override
public void run() {
    Log.i(TAG, "ItemUpload Thread started");
    isItemUploaded = true;
}
}

 private class StoreUpload extends Thread{

@Override
public void run() {
    Log.i(TAG, "StoreUpload Thread started");
    isStoreUploaded = true;
}

}

private ListUpload listUpload;
private StoreUpload storeUpload;
private ItemUpload itemUpload;

public void startUpload(){

listUpload = new ListUpload();
listUpload.start();

storeUpload = new StoreUpload();
storeUpload.start();

itemUpload = new ItemUpload();
itemUpload.start();

listUpload.join();
storeUpload.join();
itemUpload.join();

//Here comes the final block to execute after all threads finished
uploadingDone();

}
```

NOTE: Don't put thread.join() after immediate thread.start()
consider this:

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
t3.start();
t4.start();

t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
t4.join();
```

Comment: Didn't he mean in the uploadingDone() function?

Comment: @DavidOlsson no... he said that thread.join should come after all concurrent threads have joined ... if u put join of t1 before starting t2, t2 have to wait for end of the t1.